# Execute MySQL query on browser close

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm trying to execute a MySQL query when user closes his browser. 
I have managed to do with onbeforeunload but it only works in Chrome and when tab is closed.

Then I have tried with this PHP example:

```
    <?php 
    include "db/dbc.php";
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    ob_end_clean();
    echo "Testing connection handling"; 


    if (connection_status() == 1){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM online WHERE id='55'");

    }
    echo "test"; 
    flush(); 

?>
```

But this doesn't work either. Anyone has any working examples? 
I really must delete a post from a database when a browser is closed.

Comment: I doubt that there's any 100% reliable way to do what you ask.

Comment: What if I kill my browser process? If you are trying to track who is online, use a timeout at the server end. **This** won't be reliable.

Comment: dont rely on client side at all :P

Comment: i just dont understand how other sites like facebook and everybody else check if user is online or not? ideas?

Comment: You can **NOT** reliably detect when a browser window/tab is closed. The easiest solution is to simply assuming anyone who's hit your site within a certain time period is "online", then make anyone offline who hasn't hit after that period.

Comment: @Mensur then read again what DarkCthulhu said

Comment: Probably something akin to a heartbeat script.

Comment: @MarcB it would be better to use a js timeout that sends somekind of ping to the server every x minutes

Comment: u need a session management. You can hav a cron to check active sessions in every n minutes and can update DB accordingly. Nothing from client is reliable, dont trust them.

Comment: @itroubs: yes, and? that's one way of doing it. an ajax request is still a hit on the server...

Comment: @MarcB hmm i think that would be more of a philosophical question.

Answer (score 1):

We have solved this thing with cron job to check 5 minutes if user is logged in or not. 
Thank you for all ideas =)

And who voted this thingy down?

Answer (score 0):

Related to a comment clarification you have, by having code which constantly communicates with a user's browser and a session, you can identify when someone is "online". A lot of older methods related to this, especially for PHP, utilizes a database table which updates the 'Last Seen' value for a user's open session. If they haven't been 'seen' in X minutes, it would consider them 'offline'. These days, as mentioned, using AJAX and the alike, you can do much better.

As mentioned by others, this approach you're working with is not reliable and shouldn't be pursued in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and do this with Javascript and check for a window close event, but it's up to the browser on whether that is supported.

What you could do instead is create a table to log when people visit your site, and then run a cron job to check how long it has been since they changed pages. If it's been longer than X minutes set that user's status to offline.

> source - K2xL